# Nginx in Docker cannot find the file

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm running `Nginx` inside `Docker` and from logs, I can see that `Nginx` cannot find mime.types file.
The line from Nginx.conf:

```
include      mime.types;
```

Here is the `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY . ./etc/nginx
RUN ls -la /etc/nginx
```

Here is the list of files in the working directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 30 07:35 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jul 30 07:35 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            58 Jul 29 21:48 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul 29 21:36 certs
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul  6 19:40 conf.d
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1077 Jul  6 15:21 fastcgi.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1007 Jul  6 15:21 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          5290 Jul  6 15:21 mime.types
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Jul  6 19:40 modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         10729 Jul 30 07:35 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           636 Jul  6 15:21 scgi_params
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           664 Jul  6 15:21 uwsgi_params
```

And this is the error log:

```
2021/07/30 07:35:34 [emerg] 1#1: open() "/etc/nginx/mime.types" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:52
```

I can clearly see that nginx.conf is in the same directory but couldn't be found.

Docker compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  proxy:
    build: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      # - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
      # - /etc/nginx/certs

    restart: 'always'
    networks:
      - react-express
  frontend:
    build: ui
    expose:
      - 3000
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./ui:/usr/src/ui
      - /usr/src/ui/node_modules
    container_name: ui
    restart: always
    networks:
      - react-express
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    container_name: api
    restart: always
    build: api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - react-express
    expose: 
      - 8080
networks:
  react-express:
```

Comment: Try removing the leading dot in `COPY . ./etc/nginx`, i.e. try with `COPY . /etc/nginx`.

Comment: @MarkoE, good point, but doesn't help.

Comment: How about adding this to `nginx.conf`: `include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;` instead of only `mime.types`?

Comment: @MarkoE, nope, still the same error, that is very weird actually.

Comment: When you run the container, do you map any volumes into the /etc/nginx path?

Comment: @HansKilian, yes, this is from docker-compose:  
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
      - /etc/nginx/certs

Comment: @andrey.shedko When you map `./nginx:/etc/nginx`, the volume mapping wins and 'hides' the files in the image.

Comment: @HansKilian, please add this comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in the comment, you map a directory to `/etc/nginx` when you run the container.

When you map `./nginx:/etc/nginx`, the volume mapping wins and 'hides' the files in the image.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the proper way to fix this issue?

Comment: There are probably a number of ways to fix it. Can you include all the files in the image, so you don't need to map a volume? Can you instead have all the files in your host directory, so there are no files in the image to hide? Maybe you place mime.types outside the /etc/nginx path and change nginx.conf to point at it. I don't know what would work best in your case.

Comment: If you only map a few files, you could create volume mappings for each of them. Or you could create symlinks for the files you want to map in /etc/nginx/ in the image to a different directory, and then create a mapping for that directory.